# Counting Fountains

Tags: code-golf, sequence, combinatorics, restricted-time

A [fountain](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fountain.html) is arrangement of coins in rows so that each coin touches two coins in the row below it, or is in the bottom row, and the bottom row is connected. Here's a 21 coin fountain:

[image: From http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fountain.html]

---

Your challenge is to count how many different fountains can be made with a given number of coins.

You will be given as input a positive integer `n`. You must output the number of different `n`-coin fountains that exist.

Standard I/O rules, standard loopholes banned. Solutions should be able to calculate `n = 10` in under a minute.

---

Desired output for `n = 1 ... 10`:

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 15, 26, 45, 78
```

This sequence is [OEIS A005169](https://oeis.org/A005169).

---

This is code golf. Fewest bytes wins.

Comment: Is there an `n` for which the program must be guaranteed to work? (i.e. after which it may break)

Comment: @quintopia It should work for all `n`, up to limitations of datatype, hardware, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python, 57 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=0:sum(f(n-j,j)for j in range(1,i+2)[:n])or 1
```

As observed on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A005169), if you shift each row half a step relative to the row below it, the column sizes form a sequence of positive integers with a maximum upward step of 1.

The function `f(n,i)` counts the sequences with sum `n` and last number `i`. These can be recursively summed for each choice of the next column size from `1` to `i+1`, which is `range(1,i+2)`. Truncating to `range(1,i+2)[:n]` prevents columns from using more coins than remain, avoiding needing to say that negative `n`'s give `0`. Moreover, it avoids an explicit base case, since the empty sum is `0` and doesn't recurse, but `f(0)` needs to be set to `1` instead, for which `or 1` suffices (as would `+0**n`).

Comment: 17 bytes in Pyth: `M|sgL-Gd<ShHG1gQ0`

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 59 bytes

```
SeriesCoefficient[1-Fold[1-x^#2/#&,Range[#,0,-1]],{x,0,#}]&
```

Based on the Mathematica program on OEIS by Jean-François Alcover.

Comment: Can you rewrite this as a formula (I just want to compare with the formula I found)? I just cannot read Mathematica=)

Comment: @flawr The generating function of the sequence is `1/(1-x/(1-x^2/(1-x^3/(1-x^4/(1-x^5/(...))))))`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that is indeed a nice approach if you have such a powerfull CAS=)

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>60</s> 48 bytes

Thanks to @nimi for providing a way shorter solution!

```
n#p|p>n=0|p<n=sum$map((n-p)#)[1..p+1]|1<2=1
(#1)
```

Old version.

```
t n p|p>n=0|p==n=1|p<n=sum[t (n-q) q|q<-[1..p+1]]
s n=t n 1
```

The function calculating the value is `s`, implementation of the recursive formula found here: https://oeis.org/A005169

Comment: A bug: the recursive call is `t (n-p) q`. Golfing tips: use an infix operator for `t`, swap the guards and use `map` instead of the list comprehension: `n#p|p>n=0|p<n=sum$map((n-p)#)[1..p+1]|1<2=1`. `s` becomes `s=(#1)`, but  you don't have to give the main function a name at all, so `(#1)` is enough. 48 bytes.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the hints! I just started learning the basics of Haskell. I'm going to have to learn about that how the usage of `#` and `$` here first=)

Comment: A little bit of explanation:  `#` is a user defined infix function just like `+`, `*`, etc. are predefined infix functions. `$` is another way to adjust precedence (besides parentheses) `f (g (h x))`-> `f$g$h x` or in our case `sum(map(...)[...])` -> `sum$map(...)[...]`.

Comment: Thank you, that is quite useful to know, I appreciate your explanation!

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
Ms?>GHgL-GHShHqGHgQ1
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Ms%3F%3EGHgL-GHShHqGHgQ1&input=6&debug=0) [Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Ms%3F%3EGHgL-GHShHqGHgQ1&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10&debug=0)

This is a direct implementation of the recursive formula on the [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A005169), like the [Matlab answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67751/30164).

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 43 bytes

```haskell
n%i=sum[(n-j)%j|j<-take n[1..i+1]]+0^n
(%0)
```

See [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67827/20260) for explanation.

Same length with `min` rather than `take`:

```haskell
n%i=sum[(n-j)%j|j<-[1..min(i+1)n]]+0^n
(%0)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab, <s>115</s> 105 bytes

```
function F=t(n,varargin);p=1;if nargin>1;p=varargin{1};end;F=p==n;if p<n;for q=1:p+1;F=F+t(n-p,q);end;end
```

Implementation of the recursive formula found here: https://oeis.org/A005169

```
function F=t(n,varargin);
p=1;
if nargin>1
    p=varargin{1};
end;
F=p==n;
if p<n;
    for q=1:p+1;
        F=F+t(n-p,q);
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, <s>44</s> 43 bytes

```julia
f(a,b=1)=a>b?sum(i->f(a-b,i),1:b+1):1(a==b)
```

This uses recursive formula on OEIS.

Explanation

```julia
function f(a, b=1)
    if a > b
        # Sum of recursing
        sum(i -> f(a-b, i), 1:b+1)
    else
        # Convert bool to integer
        1 * (a == b)
    end
end
```

Has anyone else noticed that strike through 44 is regular 44??

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 88 bytes

```
f=lambda n,p:sum([f(n-p,q)for q in range(1,p+2)])if p<n else int(p==n)
t=lambda n:f(n,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 63

Implementing the recursive formula at OEIS page

```js
F=(n,p=1,t=0,q=0)=>p<n?eval("for(;q++<=p;)t+=F(n-p,q)"):p>n?0:1
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL, 26 bytes

```
{⍵≥⍺:⍵=⍺⋄+/(⍺-⍵)∘∇¨⍳⍵+1}∘1
```

Straightforward implementation of the first formula from the sequence explanation page. Honestly, I didn't understand anything, so let's check the results:

```
      {⍵≥⍺:⍵=⍺⋄+/(⍺-⍵)∘∇¨⍳⍵+1}∘1¨⍳10
1 1 2 3 5 9 15 26 45 78
```